# Force stop upstart job

Tags: ubuntu, upstart

I accidentally deleted some upstart job conf (in `/etc/init/`). Unfortunately I didn't set any respawn limit, and those jobs are now unstoppable.

I searched online but didn't find any answers, hope I will have better luck here.
Regards
R

PS: I'm using ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know what files you have deleted, you can:

- restore them from a backup (you have backups, right?)
- if you don't have a backup, you can locate the package that provides the file using either:

  ```
  # dpkg-query -S /path/to/file
  ```

  (if you still have the package installed; you should, you just deleted a file from it)

  ```
  # apt-file /path/to/file
  ```

  (if you don't have the packaged installed anymore, for whatever reason)

  You can also use the [Ubuntu Packages Search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) web site.
- Afterwards, when you know which package that file you deleted came from, you can just

  ```
  # aptitude reinstall package
  ```

  and the file will be there again and you will be able to stop your processes normaly.

Comment: Thx for your answer but it was custom made upstart conf file.

Comment: So, you don't have any other copy of it, say, in a repository somewhere?

Comment: They are generated by a script, I generated them back, but now way to kill them: `sudo stop my-job` answers with `my-job, start/running, process 32061`

Comment: What stops you from `SIGKILL`/`SIGTERM` them?

Comment: Well, they respawn :) But I actually figured it out. Restarting the job seems to reset to a coherent state.

Comment: Glad you sort it out.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to reproduce, and as long as the service is running, upstart will know how to stop it with `stop $svcname`. You can see if upstart knows about it with `initctl list | grep $svcname`. If upstart doesn't list it, then you should be able to kill it with `kill`. Make sure the service doesn't have its own watchdog/parent process, though, in which case you would have to kill that instead.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I see my jobs in `initctl list`, but when I `sudo stop myjob`, it ends up telling me: `my-job start/running, process 23213`.